# Can I add event to the button on click of input type=search?

Tags: javascript

Is there any event available for clicking clear button only appears on html5 search input element?

Here is my attempt. But if i use "search", the event is also triggered by pressing enter.

i.e. if i press enter, console prints out
search
clear

```js
  mySearchBar.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === ENTER_KEY_CODE) {
       console.log("search");
       //Display search results
    }
  });

  mySearchBar.addEventListener("search", () => {
    console.log("clear");
    // Click the cross button of input type=search to Clear the search results and display all
  });
};
```

Comment: what do you want to do when search is cleared?

Comment: I just don't want  console.log("clear"); is also triggered by pressing enter

Comment: Do you want to say in search input when you write some text and click enter button no event should happen ? what do you want from clear button here not understood

Comment: basically, I would like to handle them separately, pressing enter and clicking the little cross. Coz the results display are contradicted each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `eventListener 'input'` to check if input is empty each time something append to input, then if no value that mean the search input was cleared.

**EDIT:** Added value testing in keydown event

```js
mySearchBar = document.getElementById('search');
mySearchBar.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    if (!e.currentTarget.value)
      console.log('cleared');
    else
      console.log("search");
  }
});
mySearchBar.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  if (!e.currentTarget.value)
    console.log('cleared');
})
```

```html
<input type=search id=search>
```

Comment: I want to clear the result by Click the cross button of input type=search and display all. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Edited take a look, tell me if it's working for your purpose.

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for. But could you explain why pressing enter on the empty mySearchBar doesn't call console.log('cleared');

Comment: Because event is related to input not to keydown. If you want to "test" if empty when keydown simply add !e.currentTarget.value test in your keydown event.

Comment: @user16971617 answer edited take a look. If it's good for you, you can accept the answer :)